# URLs in Chrome won't delete, even when history is cleared

Tags: windows, google-chrome, history, url

I tried CCleaner and History Eraser. Nothing works.

What should I do? Also, going down over the URL and hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd> didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd> and delete the cache from Chrome.

Be sure that the URLs that are still displayed after cleaning the history are not bookmarked.